# MIME format form not processing attachment

Tags: php, forms, gmail, mime-types, office365

I've got a contact form running as a plugin on a Wordpress site I built recently, which processes the email body and attachment in mime-type format. When I tested the form in my email clients -- inbox and gmail -- I received the email properly formatted: a body copy with an attachment.

However, my client reported that incoming emails from this form were displaying code, in particular the MIME notice and content boundaries instead of the attachment, in both Gmail and Office 365. The deliver mail function can be found below. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

```
function deliver_mail() {

if ( isset( $_POST['w-submitted'] ) ) {
    $first_name = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['m-first-name'] );
    $last_name = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['m-last-name'] );
    $contact_number = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['m-contact-number'] );
    $email = sanitize_email( $_POST['m-email-address'] );
    if(isset($_POST['m-current-location'])) {
        $current_location = $_POST['m-current-location'];
    }
    $current_position = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['m-current-position'] );
    $city = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['m-city'] );
    $years_experience = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['m-experience-years'] );
    $qualifications = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['m-qualifications'] );
    if(isset($_POST['m-position'])) {
        $position = $_POST['m-position'];
    }        
    $other_position = $_POST['m-other-position'];
    if(isset($_POST['m-applied-location'])) {
        $applied_location = $_POST['m-applied-location'];
    }
    $expected_salary = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['m-expected-salary'] );
    $availability = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['m-availability'] );
    $referral_source = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['m-referral-source'] );
    if(isset($_FILES['m-upload-resume']['tmp_name'])) {
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['m-upload-resume']['tmp_name'])));
        $filename = $_FILES['m-upload-resume']['name'];
    }

    $boundary =md5(date('r', time()));

    $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );

    $subject = "Job applicant: $first_name $last_name";

    $headers = "From: $first_name $last_name <$email>" . "\r\n";

    $message = "First Name: $first_name \r\nLast Name: $last_name   \r\nContact Number: $contact_number \r\nCurrent Country: $current_location \r\nCurrent Position: $current_position \r\nCity: $city \r\nYears Experience: $years_experience \r\nQualifications: $qualifications \r\nDesired Position: $position \r\nOther Position: $other_position \r\nExpected Salary: $expected_salary \r\nAvailability: $availability \r\nReferral Source: $referral_source";

    $headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";

    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

--_2_$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message

--_2_$boundary--
--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment

$attachment
--_1_$boundary--";

    // If email has been processed for sending, display a success message
    if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers  ) ) {
        echo '<div id="contact-response">';
        echo '<p>Thank you for your interest in joining our team. We look forward to reviewing your application.</p>';
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        echo 'Sorry, an unexpected error occurred. Please refresh the page and try again.';
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `$message = "First Name:...` and `$message = "This is a multi-part message...` that seems like it's missing a concatenate for it. Try adding it `$message .= "This is a multi-part message...`

Comment: Thank you! I had a hunch that was the problem -- I've implemented that and submitted some test applications. I'll follow up once my client gets back to me with results :)

Comment: You're welcome Daniel.

Comment: Hi Fred! So it seems that adding the concatenation to the $message var didn't do the trick. After multiple tests I've confirmed that the problem is specific to Office 365 (emails are processed just fine in gmail). Any idea to why this is? Perhaps Office 365 requires a different syntax? I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with MIME-types to debug this efficiently. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi Daniel. Sorry, I have no knowledge of Office 365. Seems like an isolated case.